# what if I want add a row between different name in the table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database with the structure like:

database

```
name    Sale      company
Alice   5000      A Global
Alice   1000      C Global
Alice   2000      C Global
Bob     3000      B Corp
Alice   5000      C Global
Bob     1500      D Corp
Peter   1300      E Subject
Peter   1200      J Subject
```

If I want add a row at the end of each name with sum of Sale from Mysql. for example

```
name    Sale      company
Alice   5000      A Global
Alice   1000      C Global
Alice   2000      C Global
Alice   5000      C Global
Total: 13000
Peter   1300      E Subject
Peter   1200      J Subject
Total:  2500
```

I have tried following code

```
$sql = "SELECT `name`, Sale, company, sum(Sale) as Sale FROM `sale_report`";
$queryRecord = $conn->query($sql);
$query_sum = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
$query_sum_record = mysqli_fetch_array($query_sum);
$total=$query_sum_record['Sale'];
$name = null;
foreach($queryRecord as $res) :
if ($name && $name !== $res[name]):
echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>Total:</td><td><input value=$total></td></td></tr>";
endif;
$name = $res[name];
```

but it doesn't sum the first item(Alice) and start with the second one like this

```
name    Sale      company
Alice   5000      A Global
Alice   1000      C Global
Alice   2000      C Global
Alice   5000      C Global
Total:  2500
Peter   1300      E Subject
Peter   1200      J Subject
```

can someone fix it for me or any tips?

Comment: What? `$queryRecord = $conn->query($sql);
$query_sum = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);` Which is the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, because I use $res['name'] instead of using $name, but I don't know in detail, that is correct if use $name in sql query, hope it can help someone encount simple problem

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123321", "sale_data");
$sql = "SELECT `name`, credit FROM `report`";
$queryRecord = $connect->query($sql);   

$name = null;
echo "<table>";
foreach($queryRecord as $res) :
$sql_sum = "SELECT sum(sale) as total FROM `report` where `gp_name`='$name'";
$result_sum = mysqli_query($connect, $sql_sum);
$result_sum_query = mysqli_fetch_array($result_sum);
$total=$result_sum_query['total'];
if ($name && $name !== $res[name]):
echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>Total:</td><td><input value=$total></td></td></tr>";
endif;
$name = $res[name];
?>
<tr>
<td><input name=id type=hidden value='<?php echo $res['id'] ?>'>
<input name=gp_name type=text value='<?php echo $res['name'] ?>'></td>
<td>
<input name=Sale type=text value='<?php echo $res['total'] ?>'></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```